# Get another image if the main image is not available

Tags: php, api

I have an API, which returns some data with image links.
The problem is that there is a type of image that is main but not always available.
When that happens, I want another image to appear, but it's also in the API.

API Extract

```
"images": {
            "icon": "https://image.fnbr.co/outfit/5c2aad8560e93a37d9635605/icon.png", // secondary
            "png": false,
            "gallery": false,
            "featured": 
       "https://image.fnbr.co/outfit/5c2aad8560e93a37d9635605/featured.png" // main
 }
```

I have tried the label "onerror" but since it is not a error (because it says null) it does not replace the image.

PHP Code

```
<img src="<?php echo $image_data['data']['featured'][$i]['images'] 
['featured'] ?>";>
```

Comment: You can solve that with a simple IF statement

Answer (score 1):

you need to check if the main image is empty:

```
$images = ...; // your current image object 
$image = ($images['featured'] !== null) ? $images['featured'] : $images['icon']; // featured or icon image
```

Comment: I've added it, but I'm getting an error 500. I don't know if something can be done, but I can change the class depending on the type of object. for example,  `<img class="card-img-top <?php echo $image_data['data']['featured'][$i]['type'] ?>"`

Answer (score 0):

```
$img = $image_data['data']['featured'][$i]['images']['featured'];
$alternativ = $image_data['data']['featured'][$i]['images']['icon'];

<img src="<?php echo ($img) ? $img:$alternativ ?>";>
```

or check null

```
<img src="<?php echo ($img === NULL) ? $alternativ:$img ?>";>
```